# how to download multiple images(album) from image URL's using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, download

I have two websites. in one website i am displaying images of both websites and now i would like to keep a button as download album so that users can download those (multiple)images as album.. what should i have to do.
refereed this [Downloading multiple images files with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14485557/downloading-multiple-images-files-with-jquery) but not working.

As of now i tried with following to display image urls of the album. but dont know how to download that using src

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.mm-download-album').click(function(){ //id of mm-download-album is rel of all images which are in that album.
          var element_name = '.stackfive a[rel^="'+this.id+'"] img';
          $('.'+element_name).each(
            function(){
                alert(this.title+this.src);
               });
            });
});
```

Now using 'this.src' i want to download the images..

Edited:The following is my PHP function

```
$file = urldecode($_GET['file']);
  $title = str_replace(" ","",$_GET['title']);
  $alt = $_GET['alt'];
  if($alt != NULL) {
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$title._.$alt);
  }
  else if($alt == NULL) {
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$title);
  }
  header('Content-Type: ' . get_image_type($file));
  readfile($file);
```

Comment: In the example there is a download.php file, that is a script that takes the image src and force downloads it. So you need a script to make this work :)

Comment: @bojan in that given example  
$hrefShort = $href.replace('http://example.com/plugins/content/gallery/gallery/thumbs/', 'images\\Pics/');

What is this means.??

Comment: He is replacing the full path of the image to a relative path of the image :)

Comment: Why that is needed. without that also the image will get download..

Comment: Any way i am able to download the image and above code works.. Thank you...